# My design view no longer shows but the site runs fine.

Tags: master-pages

I use a master page for my site and for some reason, I can no longer view the master page in design view.  All that appears is a blank page with a blinking cursor.  I've been at it for over 2 hours and can't figure it out.  Yet when I run it, everything looks and behaves great.  What am I missing?

Here is the Site.Master code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<%--Here is where you reference your style sheets and JQuery library.  The link href takes the
    relative path and publishes fine for the directory.  With <script> and <style> tags, copies 
    like the JQuery reference, you will need to use the '<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl() %>' to get 
    the same relative path behavior at publishing time.  Typically you would define a code block
    and choose '<%=' however page headers don't play nice with code blocks.  '<%#' defines as a
    databinding expression and then when you add Page.Header.Databind() to your code behind for
    the master page, The DataBind method evaluates all the databinding expression(s) in your 
    header at load time--%>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<%--The ScriptManager is a what is used by the Microsoft controls to provide AJAX functionality.
    It needs to exist for the the AJAX libraries to be referenced and placing it right below the 
    Master's page Form tag is the best place--%>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                SalesPro Technologies Online 
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" 
                        LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" LogoutText="Log Out" 
                        LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>

        <div id="divMenu" class="clear hideSkiplink">

            <%-- The following code is for a traditional menu bar to appear:
                 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
                      Width="40%" Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Items>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/> 
                 </Items> 
                 </asp:Menu> --%>

            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkCss floatleft" ID="linkHome" runat="server" 
                PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkCss floatright" ID="linkAbout" runat="server" 
                PostBackUrl="~/About.aspx">About</asp:LinkButton>          
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkCss floatright" ID="linkOptions" runat="server">Options</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkCss floatright" ID="linkReports" runat="server" 
                PostBackUrl="~/reports.aspx">Reports</asp:LinkButton>  
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">     
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: UPDATE:  I removed my comments from the code and everything started working again.  Is there a way to comment and NOT lose design view?  The comments help reinforce my learning.  This has to be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your comments with ASP tags in it are confusing Visual Studio. Try removing `<%=` `<%#` `%>` from within your comments and see if that helps. If this is your problem you may need to add spaces within the tags so they don't confuse VS. ie. `< % =` You should still be able to understand your comments.

Comment: Thank you!  Once I added the spaces as you suggested everything started working again and I was able to preserve all my comments.